# Application class data being nulled out when switching to Camera Intent

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that uses a custom class with other custom classes as members. ie:

```
public class TopClass {
    public OtherClass1 otherClass1;
    public OtherClass2 otherClass2;
}
```

This data needs to be available to several other Activities. I had been storing this in the main Activity of the app and was able to reference it.

Everything is working great except when running on a Droid X2. On that device it will run fine - until an external Intent is called. The same thing happens when switching to the Camera, Maps, or Calendar Intents: after returning to the app with either the back button or, in the case of camera, the "OK" button the app will FC with NPE referencing the "TopClass"

Here is an example of the camera call for reference:

```
public void startCamera(int pos) {
    Log.v(App.DEBUG_TAG, "startCamera(slot "+pos+")");

    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(i, pos);
}
```

I switched to using an Application class to store the "TopCLass", but no change.

Using ACRA to get the stack traces and logcat where I've started logging every lifecycle event in the Activities I can see that the "TopClass" is null upon returning to the Activity. All of the local variables for the last Activity still exist in unchanged states, just the 'global' data has been nullified - GC'd, I am guessing.

I can't duplicate this on my device (Droid Incredible running CM7 [2.3.7]), or any emulator - not even the X2 addon, nor on my wife's Droid X.

I'm trying an experiment where I copy the 'global' "TopClass" to a local "TopClass" variable, but haven't heard back on whether or not that has worked yet.

My questions are:

1. What would be the proper or recommended way of persisting this data? From my reading I gathered that it was to use an Application class instance, but that isn't working.
2. Any ideas why the X2 is nulling out the Application-owned classes when calling an external Intent?

Comment: RedBinary : I use the Application Class to store the user's login credential's. But, when the user is in some activity and gets a call. The Application variables are nulled. I would like to know how to solve the problem, since you also had a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the proper or recommended way of persisting this data?

You persist data in a file. Whether that is a database, `SharedPreferences`, or a file of your own design is up to you.

> Any ideas why the X2 is nulling out the Application-owned classes when calling an external Intent?

Most likely, it is not "nulling out the Application-owned classes". Rather, your process is being terminated. Any time you are not in the foreground, your process may be terminated to free up memory for other processes, whether you are not in the foreground because you launched a third-party activity, or the user pressed HOME, or the user brought up the recent tasks list and navigated to another task, or the user received a phone call, and so on. It is possible that the X2 is more aggressive about killing off background processes than are other devices, whether specifically by design or as a side-effect of other decisions made by Motorola.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I was getting kinda slangy saying "nulled out" - intending the meaning to be "to be made null". What trips me up is that the Application class is killed and all data associated with it is lost. The Activity that calls the external Intent is not lost, however. This Activity is sent a Bundle with a custom class in it when it's started. That custom class is still viable in the Activity when returning.

Comment: @RedBinary: I don't know how you "sent a Bundle" to an activity. If you mean extras on the `Intent` used with `startActivity()`, that same `Intent` will be used to re-create the activity if the need arises (e.g., Android terminated your process, but the user BACK-buttoned their way to the activity in question, which now needs to be created again from scratch).

Comment: Sorry that I am being so unclear. Yes. I declared an Intent and I declared a Bundle. I used the Bundle's putSerializable() method to include the custom class. I then used Intent's putExtras() method to include the Bundle that has the serialized custom class. Then I start the Activity in question with startActivity(intent). I just thought "This Activity is sent a Bundle with a custom class in it when it's started" was sufficient. I apologize.

Comment: You figured out what I meant, though. Thank you for the explanation - it does help to clear it up for me somewhat.

Comment: It now occurs to me that since the mentioned Intent including the Bundle is persistent enough to be used to "re-create the activity if the need arises" and "TopClass" is serializable would you recommend against using the same method to persist it in the circumstances? If so, why?

Comment: @RedBinary: This is not persistence. This is maintaining some amount of context. If you *only* care about this problem for the very narrow scenario you outline here, perhaps it will work. If, however, you also need to solve this problem for the scenario where the user presses HOME and leaves your app for a month, you should solve it once to cover both scenarios.

Comment: Appreciated. The requirement is just to maintain state and session data across dropping out to and back from the camera, calendar, and maps Intents: login credentials and a block of records received from a server. Probably more data than should be sent through an Intent. I did some toying with it and it appears that it was functional, but ended up preferring to flatten into JSON and cache in the SharedPreferences. Thank you again for the insight!